# How to get data from service POST

Tags: php

I'm creating a PHP file that receives through POST data from a credit card company.
But I don't know how to get the specific data from this post.
here's a example of what I receive:

```
event=invoice.created&data%5Bid%5D=63BDD6B5E73144DEAE77AD3B41AC9F15&data%5Bstatus%5D=pending&data%5Bsubscription_id%5D=15708D82D2F74502AB628B4068EFDA38
```

so for example, if I want to get the `"status"` property shouldn't I use `$status = $_POST["status"]`? but it doesn't work!

My question is... how do I access the data from this post?

Comment: Try using `print_r($_POST)` to see what you're working with

Comment: I can't print it... This php file is accessed by another server, I have this post info because I saved it on a database using $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); $iuguRequest = $input; and saving it on a DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to use `$_POST['data']['status']`.

If you only have raw POST data, you need to parse it with [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str($raw_post_data, $post_data);
$status = $post_data['data']['status'];
```